# Showing file sizes in sorted order

Tags: command-line

How to show a list of files from some directory root sorted in file size descending order from command line?

Comment: `ls -lS` sorts files from largest to smallest.  `man ls` will show you this.

Answer (score 5):

From your folder:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort --human-numeric-sort --reverse
```

You can set how deep it can look for files with `-maxdepth` parameter or without it to be recursive.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to list everything in the directory recursively, use either `find` or `du` with `sort`:

```
find /some/path -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn
du -h /some/path | sort -rh
```

The former will show only files, and size in bytes. The latter will show both file and cumulative directory sizes, in human-readable (using KB, MB, etc.) format. `sort` accordingly uses numeric for the former (`-n`) and human-readable for the latter (`-h`).

---

With more complexity, the best option would be:

```
find /some/path -type f -print0 | du --files0-from=- -0h | sort -rzh | tr '\0' '\n'
```

`du` can read a NUL-delimited list of files from input, and `find` can print NUL-delimited filenames using `-print0`. `sort` can then take the NUL-delimited list of sizes and filenames and sort them, and finally you replace NULs with newlines for convenient display.

Since filenames and paths can contain anything except the ASCII NUL character, using NUL-delimited lines will processing them is the safest way.

You can also get `find` to print the size as seen in the first command, but with `-printf '%s %p\0'` to still use NUL-delimited lines, and skip using `du` as the middle man.

Answer (score 1):

As @Terrance said, `ls -lS` sorts files in descending order. For all of the files, `ls -lSa` works.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to use `du` and `sort`

```
du --max-depth 1 * | sort -n -k1
```

Example of the output ,

```
$ du --max-depth 1 * | sort -n -k1
4   bin/CS-1400
4   bin/csrc
4   bin/DIR@YOLO
4   bin/EET2350
4   bin/HW6
4   RS232Functions.c
4   RS232Functions.c~
4   Untitled Folder
8   1204686.docx_en-US_zh-CN.docx
8   bin/shell
16  MSUDenver_50th_Formal.png
20  bb0239ba-1718-4778-b19a-3826f36a95cd.png
20  mainLogo.png
24  bin/NAME WITH SPACES
32  bin/ala
32  bin/Online_book
60  bin/HORTON
72  bin/JAVA-OTHER
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will sort by size in kb

```
du -sk * | sort -n
```

You can reverse it with:

```
du -sk * | sort -rn
```